# I want to set back button text on navigation bar But I can't. This Code Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Back"
```

I want to set back button text on navigation bar But I can't. This Code Not Working.

Comment: What does "This Code Not Working." mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

As per the comment of @Boobesh, the solution that worked as per the question:

```
let vc = ViewController() 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title : "Back", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil) 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

### Original Answer

Try adding this code in the view controller one level up the stack.

If you are moving from controller A to B, write this code on A to see the effect on B.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
  backItem.title = "Back"
  navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem // This will show in the next view controller being pushed
}
```

Comment: Sorry Its Not Working ...

Comment: now it's working I just added some work.

Comment: please add that code you've added extra here also so that it'll be helpful for someone who will search this in the future

Comment: `let vc = ViewController()
       
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(title : "Back", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

I Just Added That Where am push the vc ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Text"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem //
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Try to put this code in the controller you coming from

Comment: Sorry Its Not Working ...

Comment: now it's working I just added some work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Text", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Add this code to the controller (viewDidLoad method for instance) to which you return, not the one from which you are returning. So, if the stack of view controllers looks like:
`ViewController1 -> ViewController2` and you want to change the back button title on the `ViewController2`, you need to change the `backbuttonItem` of the `ViewController1`.

Comment: Sorry Its Not Working ...

Comment: now it's working I just added some work.